# Prestashop - Custom field on admin CMS Page

Tags: controller, overriding, prestashop

I am trying to add a new field in the administration of a CMS page, but when I modify the renderForm function of the AdminCmsController class, my modifications are not taken.
I'm on prestashop 1.7.6, or is this file no longer used, since I completely deleted the content of this file but that has no impact?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not as simple as it used to be in PrestaShop 1.6

A few months ago I had such a request and to add one additional field I had to modify the following files:

- /public_html/src/Adapter/CMS/Page/CommandHandler/AddCmsPageHandler.php
- /public_html/src/Adapter/CMS/Page/CommandHandler/EditCmsPageHandler.php
- /public_html/src/Core/Domain/CmsPage/Command/AddCmsPageCommand.php
- /public_html/src/Core/Domain/CmsPage/Command/EditCmsPageCommand.php
- /public_html/src/Core/Domain/CmsPage/QueryResult/EditableCmsPage.php
- /public_html/src/Core/Form/IdentifiableObject/DataHandler/CmsPageFormDataHandler.php
- /public_html/src/Core/Form/IdentifiableObject/DataProvider/CmsPageFormDataProvider.php
- /public_html/src/Adapter/CMS/Page/QueryHandler/GetCmsPageForEditingHandler.php
- /public_html/src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Improve/Design/Pages/CmsPageType.php
- /public_html/classes/CMS.php

An additional field was saved in the database in the `cms` table, hence the change of the CMS class.

**Actually, I don't recommend this solution unless you have no choice. Currently, I would create an additional module for this and use hooks to attach it to the form.**